# Pass Class of a type parameter which may itself be parametrized in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, types

I have the following class that gets its type's class passed in its constructor:

```
class Foo<T>{
    Foo(Class<T> clazz){
        //do something
    }
}
```

My problem is, if I want T to be of a generic type, I cannot pass its class as the argument unless I use raw types:

```
Foo<List> f = new Foo(List.class);
```

This compiles alright but how can I change the constructor to be able to instantiate an object of type `Foo<List<Integer>>`?

```
Foo<List<Integer>> f1 = new Foo(List.class);
```

doesn't work because `List` != `List<Integer>` and I can't do `List<Integer>.class` because of type erasure. What I'm doing right now is doing an unchecked cast but there's gotta be a better way:

`Foo<List<Integer>> f2 = (Foo<List<Integer>>)new Foo(List.class);`

I want to use this to conveniently encapsulate field access via reflection. This is an example of how I'm using it:

```
class StaticField<V> {
    private final Field field;
    StaticField(Class<?> declaringClass, String fieldName, Class<V> valueClass){
        //instantiate field and do some error handling including an
        //assertion whether field.getType() == valueClass
    }
    public V get(){...}
    public void set(V value){...}
}
```

Comment: What is the Class passed as argument used for in Foo?

Comment: You're looking for Jackson `TypeReference` or Guava `TypeToken`.

Comment: @JBNizet I have to use a lot of reflection in my project (a video game mod) so I created a convenient class to encapsulate access to private or final fields. The type T is the type of the referenced field. The class is used to check in the constructor whether the field is of the correct type. I added a more detailed code snipped to my post.

Answer (score 0):

To be completely honest, there is no *true* way to do what you want, because at runtime the VM doesn't have access to the info needed to avoid the type erasure - at that prevents your class from having the info to return the correspondant class, so it can just return at most the same class parameter you provide.